# Drag and drop action is not working in selenium, it is not showing any error as well

Tags: selenium-webdriver, drag-and-drop

I am trying to drag and drop an element from a list, user needs to click on the ellipses and the drag drop the element to destination. I tried with different ways but it's not working and it does not throw any error. My test case is also showing as passed with out performing drag and drop.

I want the Entrepreneur to be dragged and dropped to the location of Professor but it's not working at all.

below is the html for the same

```
<div class="row role"><div class="col-sm-7 role-name">Entrepreneur</div><div class="col-sm-5"><!----><span class="one-glober"><!----><!----></span><i class="fa fa-bars pull-right drag-roles"></i></div></div>


<li id="2" draggable="false" class="active" style=""><div class="row role"><div class="col-sm-7 role-name">Professor</div><div class="col-sm-5"><!----><i class="fa fa-bars pull-right drag-roles"></i></div></div></li>
```

i have tried below ways to do so  but none of them is working.

```
    @FindBy(xpath="//li[@id='2']//i[@class='fa fa-bars pull-right drag-roles']")
    private WebElement source;

    @FindBy(xpath="//li[@id='4']//i[@class='fa fa-bars pull-right drag-roles']")
    private WebElement destination;

    public CharacterRoleDragDropPage dragAndDrop() throws InterruptedException {

        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOf(loader));

        Actions action= new Actions(driver);
        //action.dragAndDrop(source, destination).build().perform();
        //action.clickAndHold(source).moveToElement(destination).release().build().perform();
        source.click();
        //action.clickAndHold(source).dragAndDropBy(source,0, 500).build().perform();
        //action.clickAndHold(source).moveByOffset(0, 500).moveToElement(destination).build().perform();    
        //action.clickAndHold(source).moveToElement(destination).release(source).build().perform();
        action.clickAndHold(source).dragAndDrop(source, destination).build().perform();
        return this;

    }
```

Comment: It would be useful to have a URL so we can see what you are trying to run this code against, the small HTML snippets on their own don't really tell us how the content is rendered.

Answer (score 1):

I also had trouble with `drag  & drop` and figured, if I used `moveByOffset` method with a combination of `pause` it started to work.

You can try below code:

```
new Actions(driver)
    .moveToElement(source)
    .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .clickAndHold(source)
    .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .moveByOffset(1, 0)
    .moveToElement(destination)
    .moveByOffset(1, 0)
    .pause(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .release().perform();
```

Comment: Hi Fenio, I tried your solution but it is still not working.